# RSpec - model uniqueness testing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to make some simple model test:

/app/models/album.rb:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :slides, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

/spec/model/album_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Album do
    before do
        @album = Album.new(name: 'Example Album')
    end

    describe "when album name is already taken" do
        before do
            another_album = @album.dup
            another_album.save
        end

        it { should_not be_valid }
    end
end
```

I was expecting it to fail first (as I have no `validates :uniqueness` and index on the name field) but it passed. So I changed:

`it { should_not be_valid }`
to
`it { should be_valid }`

To see what's going on and this is what I got:

```
 1) Album when album name is already taken should be valid
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected #<Album id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Name can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/album_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I would like to ask you what I did wrong.

One more thing is if I can/should use `expect` rather than `should` syntax here ? I read somewhere that `should` is a bit deprecated and not `expect` is recomended but I don't know how to use it for model testing (I have it on my Controller/View test in form of `expect(page)` or `expect(current_path)`. What argument can I use for model ?

Comment: is it possible here to accept two answers ? as both are very useful for me

Comment: you can only accept one answer but can up vote both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup an `explicit subject` before your example:

```
subject {@album}
it { should_not be_valid }
```

Currently, as per the failure error`#<Album id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>` an implicit blank instance of `Album` is created as no `explicit subject` is found before the example.

Comment: I need to add validation and index to confirm that but I suppouse `subject {@another_album}` should be correct, right ?

Comment: As per your question, you wanted to check the validation for `uniqueness`(later). So, subject should be `@album` as `@another_album ` is already saved in database.

Comment: At first `before` statement I saved `@album` than I'm trying to dup it as `@another_album` and save it (I think I should use `@` which is missing in my original question). I'm still confused. I'll make the migration and check.. give me a minute

Comment: All of you are right. I added index and validation to the model and now it's working fine. I still don't get why it doesn't work with `@another_album` but I'll find out reading doc shown above I hope.

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen the `it` syntax that you are using. First thing, I would checkout the quick start documentation available here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#model-specs and then make sure that you are familiar with this set of docs as well: http://rspec.info/

From the example on github:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe User do
  it "orders by last name" do
    lindeman = User.create!(first_name: "Andy", last_name: "Lindeman")
    chelimsky = User.create!(first_name: "David", last_name: "Chelimsky")

    expect(User.ordered_by_last_name).to eq([chelimsky, lindeman])
  end
end
```

You would want to change your second `describe` to an `it` and then use one or more `expect` to determine if the test passes. `it` takes a string that appears in the test output. So generally you want to make it something expressive. Additionally there is no need to use before blocks here. You can do everything in the `it` block:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Album do
  it "fails validation when album name is already taken" do
    album = Album.new(name: 'Example Album')
    another_album = album.dup
    expect {another_album.save!}.to  raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid,'Validation failed: This question is no longer active.')
  end
end
```

Comment: I like that `another_album.save!` is not in `before` block but in `expect`s action. This is much clearer for me how it should work. I'll try to follow this way.